# disable incognito mode in ChromeOS (ChromeBook)

Tags: google-chrome-os, private-browsing

Is there a way to disable incognito mode in ChromeOS (like a ChromeBook) other than Google's Supervised User? I am interested in doing it on my personal ChromeBooks (they are not enterprise devices).

Answer (score 2):

#### Is there a way to disable incognito mode in ChromeOS?

> To disable incognito on chrome/chromium you need to edit the policies.
>   Doing this will prevent you from opening an incognito window via
>   Ctrl+Shift+n, and will also grey out the incognito window option in
>   the options tab in the corner.
>
> If you're using chrome, create the folder
>   /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed .  Or if you're using chromium,
>   create the folder /etc/chromium/policies/managed .
>
> Then create a file in that directory named test_policy.json . It can
>   have any name you want, but it needs the extension to be .json.
>
> Open it in your favorite  editor and put:
>
> ```
> {
>     "IncognitoModeAvailability": 1
> }
> ```
>
> That should do it!
>
> Source: http://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start and
>   http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3

Source [How to disable Chrome's Incognito Mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116319/how-to-disable-chromes-incognito-mode), [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/367058/376050) by [ryan](https://askubuntu.com/users/208551/ryan)

Comment: You can't access root filesystem in ChromeOS, so how can one create that file? I guess you are confused with Chrome on Ubuntu as being same as ChromeOS?

Comment: Actually you can modify the filesystem, it's not a nice solution as it breaks verification and probably auto updates but it's possible in developer mode: [Making changes to the filesystem](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/poking-around-your-chrome-os-device#TOC-Making-changes-to-the-filesystem). I haven't found a way to tell Chrome to just start with incognito mode disabled by modifying contents on the stateful partition or modifying the launcher item.