# Unable to boot into Chromebook after blocking incognito mode

Tags: linux, google-chrome, chromium, chromebook, google-chrome-os

[disable incognito mode in ChromeOS (ChromeBook)](https://superuser.com/questions/916640/disable-incognito-mode-in-chromeos-chromebook)

So i followed this and it works but my Chromebook doesn't boot up after shutdown

I recovered the chromebook back to normal using traditional recovery

But whats the problem?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: I am a newbie and i am learning

I have only tried what was given in the link which i sent